# Quartz.NET - getting jobs exception using IJobListener

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET for an application I am creating, and I currently have an IJobListener listening for any errors with jobs, then sending emails off to the administrators. It'd be great if I could email the exception generated too, but how do I get the exception from the IJobListener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`JobWasExecuted`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic34.html) method is passed a [`JobExecutionException`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic415.html) (if one was thrown during the triggering of the job).

Comment: If it wouldn't be burden for you, please show some code of how to error handle in quartz.net( I mean common practice )

Comment: take a look at Java example: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07.html